# What is the full name of this Cinelli bike model?

Tags: vintage

[image]
[image]
[image]

Tell me, does anyone know the full name of this Cinelli bike model? I will be grateful, thank you!

Comment: Anyway, you can be certain you have a high quality frame when it is made with such a fancy bottom bracket

Answer (score 6):

A-ha! but it's not a Cinelli.

A frame builder has built this using commercially available lugs and shells including the very famous Cinelli bottom bracket shell.

The frame builder is most likely to be Presti, as stamped at the top of the seat stay.

[image: text]

[image: bottom bracket shell]

These images are from the Cinelli page for the Supercorsa frameset.

Comment: That is some magnificent spotting !

Comment: But Presti did not find such a manufacturer. In my opinion, the name is written at this place, such as Celo Europa Colnago. There is also a "C" mark on it and on the fork. And his frame is very similar to mine. Also in my logo on the fork there is a part of the Colnago logo. Still, I think my bike has a certain model (I would like to believe).

Comment: @СтасСклюев There are many manufacturers that use this bottom bracket, often quite small or Artisan builders. Presti may be a pre-internet era small manufacturer that only lasted a few years, some of them are like this. The only thing you have for certain is that the Cinelli bottom bracket dates the bike to after 1984